# Passing multiple variables from Python to MATLAB

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, python-3.7

I have a Python (version 3.7.9) code that looks like this

```
def matgenerator(number):
    import numpy as np

    mat = np.zeros((2,4))
    mat1 = number + mat
    mat2 = number*mat

    return mat1, mat2
```

When I ran this function in MATLAB as follows

```
py.matgenerator.matgenerator(number)
```

I expected two ndarray variables (which I can easily convert to double type in MATLAB) but instead I am getting a single variable of 1x2 tuple.

Is there a way to directly pass more than one numpy array variables from Python to MATLAB?

Comment: Is the returned variable the tuple `(mat1, mat2)`? Or are you only getting `mat1` back? Have you tried `[mat1, mat2] = py.matgenerator.matgenerator(number)`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am getting a tuple `(mat1, mat2)`. I tried `[mat1, mat2] = py.matgenerator.matgenerator(number)` but I am getting an error that reads **No method by py.matgenerator.matgenerator(number) with matching signature found**

Comment: If you get the tuple back, then you've got all the data, no? You can probably extract the two matrices by indexing: `retval = py.matgenerator.matgenerator(number); mat1 = retval{1}; mat2 = retval{2};`. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pythontuplevariables.html